# override add method entityCollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm looking for a way to add logic in the function `Add` of an entityCollection before the actual add
when you have an entity who have an entityCollection you can do for exemple :

```
car.passengers.Add(passenger)
```

I want to check that there is no more than 5 passengers for example
so i try an extension like that:

```
static public void Add(this EntityCollection<passenger> Passenger, Passenger Passenger)
{
    // some logique (in fact i want throw an exception here to force the utilisation of the controller)
}
```

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Entity Framework is for data access, not business logic.  This should really be handled by your business logic layer.

Answer (score 0):

Remember open/closed principle and always use inheritance to extend the functionality never modify the base class behavior. Given that `EntityCollection` is `sealed`, you can use a `PassengerRepository` class which deals with the passenger related operations, which will also be easy to unit test. Using an extension method for this purpose sounds very very hackish.